# How can I set the width of a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'd like to ensure that the width of popup window falls within set dimensions using javascript/jquery (i.e. popup window size is 700 x 500). I assume this is not feasible strictly through CSS--I doubt a simple styling of the body tags height and width will not ensure the proper size everytime it pops up. The code I was using below does not work, and I'm not entirely sure why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.resizeTo(500,500)
});
```

Comment: you can set the window size in the [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Position_and_size_features) function

Comment: You should use your title in google...

Comment: Being new to JS, I didn't think what I found on Google was quite fitting, and having additional input or perspectives always helps me learn. So, thanks for the downvotes, I'm sure you're all better programmers because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example taken from developer.mozilla.org

```
windowObjectReference = window.open(
    "http://www.domainname.ext/path/ImgFile.png",
    "DescriptiveWindowName",
    "width=420,height=230,resizable,scrollbars=yes,status=1"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('popup.html','resizable=no,height=700,width=500');
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to set the element style using JavaScript with some calculations with the window's height and width ( document.height, document.width ). So, check if the window size is bigger than 1024 ( or something like that ), then set the height of the content ( of the popup ) to 700, and if the size of the document is less... Make a calculation with to achieve your desired size, something like this;

`document.getElementById('divId').style.height = window.height / 2 )`